# How many Ethereum contracts have been published?

Tags: accounts, addresses, contract-deployment, explorers, statistics

Is there a place to see how many Ethereum contracts have been published?

If someone wanted to calculate that, it would just be total number of accounts minus accounts with code, right? Any suggestions on an easy way to calculate this? It seems like a meaningful metric for Ethereum.

Comment: how to get `total number of accounts` ?

Comment: Etherscan has an [address growth graph](http://etherscan.io/charts/address) but that doesn't say anything about how many people are just speculating. I'm wondering how much is Ethereum actually being used for its capabilities... even if it is just a "hello world" contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some places you can find the information you are looking for:

- https://etherchain.org/contracts - a bit harder to calculate as you will have to navigate through the many pages.
- https://etherscan.io/accounts/c - currently shows a total of 19,806 accounts.
- https://live.ether.camp/contracts - this site has a smaller subset of contract accounts listed. I have not looked into their criteria for determining this subset.

The three URLs above shows you the contract accounts only, so you don't have to separate these from normal accounts from your calculations.

As a meaningful metric, you will have to take into account the many test contracts, e.g. https://www.ethereum.org/token.

Comment: That's great, thank you. Etherchain and Etherscan are off by ~200 contracts, but that's close enough for what I was looking for. Strangely, Ether Camp is off from those two by like ~19k... unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

[Amberdata.io](https://amberdata.io) has [an API](https://docs.amberdata.io/reference#get-all-addresses) that can do this pretty easily:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://web3api.io/api/v1/addresses?type=contract' \
  --header 'x-api-key: <x-api_key>'
```

Response:

```
{
  "status":200
  "title":"OK"
  "description":"Successful request"
  "payload":{
    "totalRecords":6505274
    "records":[
      0:{...}
      1:{...}
      ...
    ]
    }
}
```

`totalRecords` would be the total amount of smart contracts. As of running this query there are **6,505,274** smart contracts.

Let me know if that's helpful!